# Proving some sequence of integers by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Say I have a sequence like:

$0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,\dots$ in other words $1=0$, next $2=1$, third $3=2$ etc. and a formula that I believe works for my sequence.

How would I prove that the sequence works for the induction? I mean I can't really see any mathematical operations that apply to a "set" like that?

The formula I believe works for any $n$ is $f(x) = x \bmod 3 $

Comment: Does the first integer represent 1 or 0?If it represents 1,then your formula should be $x+2\pmod 3$

Comment: It's a sequence where 1 = 0, 2 = 1, 3 = 0, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 3=2?

Comment: Yes...Sorry, I'm getting a bit overcooked atm.

Answer (score 0):

Write how you define mathematically your sequence and you will see how to prove that : 0, 1, 2, ... makes "no sense" as a definition

$u_0 = 0$ and if $u_n=0$ $u_{n+1} = 1$ and so on